# Plus Sign (+) Appears In String For C# Collection Type Name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, types

I never saw (or noticed) this before, but I am seeing a plus sign (+) within the string that expresses a data type in the immediate window within Visual Studio while using C#.

To see what I'm talking about, consider this simple code:

```
var myConverter = new System.ComponentModel.BooleanConverter();
var standardValuesCollection = myConverter.GetStandardValues();
```

If I go to the VS Immediate Window and type this:

```
?standardValuesCollection.GetType().ToString()
```

Visual Studio reports this:

```
"System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter+StandardValuesCollection"
```

Notice the "+" after the string "TypeConverter" above.

Yet when I hover over the **standardValuesCollection** in code, I see only a reference to the expected System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection:

[image]

What's the plus sign indicating in the Immediate Window string description of the type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that the StandardValuesCollection is defined as a child class of TypeConverter:

```
namespace System.ComponentModel
{
    public class TypeConverter 
    {
        public class StandardValuesCollection  {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about the inconsistent use of the + sign? For example, why would the Immediate Window convey the child class information using a + sign but the hover-over tooltip on running code does not? Wouldn't that child-class detail be helpful in both citations?

Comment: The immediate window shows the ToString value of the class. It is C# practice to have the bar behaviour of ToString to print the type name nested classes are always printed as ParentClassName+NestedClassName. The tootip you see is intelisense and comes from the metadata of the .DLL that's why there is a difference